# How to obtain last-known occurrence of closest match to a value after passing the maximum value?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a set of data with temperature (column A) and time (column B). The temperature increases over time, hits a peak ~100F and then decreases. I have a set of high/low reference temperatures (e.g. 80F and 60F). Is there a formula/VBA code that would output the **last occurrence** of the closest value to the ref. temperatures *only within the cooling down region* (i.e. within data after passing max temp peak)? I am currently looking through it manually and selecting the values e.g. 82F and 59F.

Side note: Even thought the temperature might hit exactly the ref temp on the way up, I need to output the closest value to it on the way down.

Hope someone can help. Thanks!

Comment: I did this, it gets the smallest difference and adds to the reference, so I was using `=MIN(ABS(($A$1:$A$8-$D$1)))+$D$1` where D1 is my reference temp.  This is an array so ctrl shift enter.  Without seeing the data, I cant comment much more, but I did a simple increase.  Have a play, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using a max value of 100, and a threshold of 85, I used the following.  You can use cells to hold the values, I've just added so you can see where they go.

`=MIN(ABS((INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(100,A:A,0)&":A20")-85)))+85`

I also have 20 rows of data, hence the A20, you can put a count on that.